# X11 xorg Electron App cant open in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, linux, electron, xorg

We have an electron app running on X11 without a Window Manager -> directly on the XServer.

We can't get electron to get in fullscreen!

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win;

function createWindow () {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        fullscreen:true,
        "web-preferences": { "web-security": false }
        //icon: `file://${__dirname}/dist/assets/logo.png`
    })


    win.loadFile(`app/index.html`)

    //// uncomment below to open the DevTools.
    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Event when the window is closed.
    win.on('closed', function () {
        win = null
    })
}

// Create window on electron intialization
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

We also tried using setFullscreen, nothing works.

The xserver uses the whole screen, so there's no problem with it. Chromium started in fullscreen - no problems.
[image: The screen]

If we start Electron with an Window Manager, we can press F11 afterwards to make it full size but still doesn't work programmaticly

We tried:

- Setting the width and height with the resolution from the screen itself in the  BrowserWindow Constructor.
- Setting Kiosk with .setKiosk(true) and in options kiosk: true
- Setting Fullscreen with .setFullscreen(true) and fullscreen: true

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old question, but how did you manage to run electron app on raspbian lite I just have x-server installed and ssh-ed it. I used electron-packager and built packages but after copying files it does not work.

I need to have a very minimal version of Debian and oh I did not install node as i suppose it is not needed to run packaged apps

Comment: We didn't even package it. It is a bad practise to do so, but it was just a school project so we didn't care => we just started with "electron ." so no packager or anything else. @Rati_Ge

Comment: I See but cannot understand why packing or creating .deb is a bad idea there after all if this is a commercial product you can not force clients to download full node environment and npm and restore staff during install and leave sources open on the device.

Comment: No no! Packaging is the way to go!! I meant that I *didn't* package it because it was just a school project. That's why I can't help you with that. Packaging is best practice. Now that I read my comment I should rephrase that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was the app wasn't run from electron itself, my script started the index.html file, not the app!

Comment: It's great to hear you figured it out! If you're satisfied with your answer you should accept it by clicking the green tick below the voting buttons.

Comment: @Mike Have to wait 12h before I can mark my own question :p

Answer (score 3):

This might not be what you want but there is a option called `kiosk` this is basically fullscreen mode exept the page covers the entire screen. Also you can't escape from it until kiosk mode is turned off.

To activate you can either call `setKiosk(true)`. Or set `kiosk: true` in the browser window options

[`setKiosk` Docs.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetkioskflag)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is specifically for Linux Xorg. It has been tested on Fedora 39.0 GNOME Xorg, Electron v28.1.0.

---

To make the window fullscreenable on Linux, in Xorg window manager, you can set `fullscreen` to true and set the window initially frameless. Then remove the fullscreen and you can make the window fullscreen whenever you want to.

```js
var window = new BrowserWindow({
  fullscreen: true,
  frame: false
});
window.setFullScreen(false);
```

The only problems with this are:

1. The window is frameless
2. Changes to the window size & toggling fullscreen sometimes behave weird